# Creating angularjs modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was just looking at the source-code of `angular-flash` which is below:
https://github.com/gtramontina/angular-flash/blob/master/angular-flash.js

Can anyone explain me on how he is creating the `flash` module

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        // CommonJS
        module.exports = factory(root, require('angular'));
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['angular'], function (react, angular) {
            return (root.angularFlash = factory(root, angular));
        });
    } else {
        // Global Variables
        root.angularFlash = factory(root, root.angular);
    }
}(this, function (window, angular) {
    return angular.module('flash', []);
}));
```

What i am not understanding is argument `factory` which is being received and the `root.angularFlash` variable? How does this create a `angular module flash`?

I don't see anywhere the `angularFlash` variable too used?

Comment: `angular.module('flash', [])` [from docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Comment: this is an IIFE, that takes two parameters, the first being the context the module is being created in, the second being the `function(window, angular) {...` that is actually creating the module and the factory object.  depending on the type of module loader in use, the function is strapped in to the loader to either be executed immediately or when the loader calls upon it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
        // CommonJS
        module.exports = factory(root, require('angular'));
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['angular'], function (react, angular) {
            return (root.angularFlash = factory(root, angular));
        });
    } else {
        // Global Variables
        root.angularFlash = factory(root, root.angular);
    }
}(this, function (window, angular) {
    return angular.module('flash', []);
}));
```

If you look at the IIFE at the bottom it's calling passing an anonymous function as the second argument which is named factory that defined the angular module flash:

```
factory = function (window, angular) {
    return angular.module('flash', []);
}
```

So when factory is invoked it's basically defining a module named flash.

Comment: Add the module in the context. in the browser will be window.angularFlash. This is the basic format of an UMD format

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this script is running in a browser context (as opposed to CommonJS or AMD).

The outer function, starting with `function (root, factory) ...`, is an example of an immediately-invoked function expression, or IIFE.  This outer function is invoked with the arguments `this` and a function (which gets bound to `factory` parameter).  The keyword `this` refers to the global `window` object in this case.

So, the effect of this function is essentially identical to:

```
window.angularFlash = window.angular.module('flash', [])
```

This creates the module with the name `flash` and binds the global variable `angularFlash` to it, which can be used to refer to the module elsewhere in the code.